# get submitted form's post_id from outside the loop PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on an app that has a post form that matches up adoption mentors with mentees.
This is in Wordpress/PHP/MySQL/ACF (Advanced Custom Field).

After the form has been submitted, I am unable to get the post_id for that post so I can save the ACF field "title" for the screen that lists all the matches.

Do I need to retrieve that form's `$post_id` when I'm "outside the loop"? And how do I do that?

```
function match_post_title_auto( $post_id ) {

    // get mentor & new mentee user array
    $mentee = get_field('match_mentee', $post_id);
    $mentor = get_field('match_mentor', $post_id);

    $title = ' Mentor: ' . $mentor['display_name'] . ' and Mentee: ' . $mentee['display_name']; 

    $postdata = array(
         'ID'          => $post_id,
         'post_title'  => $title,
         'post_type'   => 'match'
    );

    wp_update_post( $postdata );
    return $value;
}

var_dump($post_id);  //returns NULL

//what do I put here to get that `post_id`? Thanks!

add_action('acf/save_post', 'match_post_title_auto', 10, 1);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. What form are you talking about? As-is, your function looks like it will change the title of any post that has custom fields when it is saved, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're trying to do. Also you're passing three parameters to your function when that filter only accepts one, $post_id

Comment: Your "var_dump($post_id);  //returns NULL" is not working is expected. You are accessing $post_id outside the function scope. Turn one wordpress debug option https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress and use error_log() to troubleshoot your code in function match_post_title_auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `acf/save_post` hook only passes the `$post_id` as single parameter. You have 3 parameters in your callback. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/. Also, you need to have a priority higher than 10 to get the *updated* values from your post.

```
function match_post_title_auto( $post_id ) {
    // do stuff
}
add_filter('acf/save_post', 'match_post_title_auto', 20 );
```

Comment: Thank you all, you've been a big help. I'll digest & test this & get back with you.

Comment: This was a big help in understanding the issue. Once everything was configured properly, it was able to find the post_id.
I have it set at: add_action('acf/save_post', 'match_post_title_auto', 20);
I am, however, puzzled by the update_field() writing to the database having a lag in some cases. Is there a setting to make that happen quicker? Or could it be due to some sort of caching issue? I couldn't find much documentation on the priority setting.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to catch the values by filter hook. Actually you need action hook and 1 parameter only. like this:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'match_post_title_auto', 10, 1);
```

Hope it will work.

> for more information, check the standard documentation: 
>   https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Comment: `add_action` calls `add_filter`, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: yep, sometimes that's right. but in that case apply_filters hooks needed to be fired too. Here when they said it in the doc. that, it should call by add_action that means you need to call it by that way. so basically they are firing do_action hook in their end. take a look here for brief of these hooks - https://wpsmith.net/2011/the-difference-between-do_action-add_action-and-add_filter/